# Give input 'name' attribute for cloned inputs, that is inside a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

So this is my case. I have a unordered list and inside a list a set of inputs and one button that can clone 4 of those inputs. Since data is coming from back-end, there can be one of this list set or 1000. So i am trying to dynamically give name attributes to each input inside the list based on list index number and figure out a way to do that for the cloned inputs also. if you look at the class **pm-providerNum** I am doing something similar to the provider name so its based on how many lists.if I add more lists the provider name auto change. Back to names, so for li number 1, on each input except the dynamically created ones.  each input name would be like this

On dynamic inputs like add location, input name would be :

```
   <input type="text" name="p-address-0-dynamic#[dynamicnumber]" class="pm-
   psubmit" placeholder="First Name" required="">
```

etc ....
dynamicnumber is the number that says the number of newly created inputs. 
so if no additional location is added to providor 1/index 1 , each input name  on 
dynamic inputs would be :

```
     <input type="text" name="p-address-0-dynamic#[0]" class="pm-psubmit" 
     placeholder="First Name" required="">
```

if I add one additional location. those inputs would name would be

```
     <input type="text" name="p-address-0-dynamic#[1]" class="pm-psubmit" 
     placeholder="First Name" required="">
```

on list 2/index 2

```
    <input type="text" name="p-address-1-dynamic#[0]" class="pm-psubmit" 
    placeholder="First Name" required="">
```

if i add one additional location. those inputs would name would be

```
    <input type="text" name="p-address-1-dynamic#[1]" class="pm-psubmit" 
    placeholder="First Name" required="">
```

I spend some time creating this question, it might be confusing, hopefully, you guys got what I am trying to say. I tried a bunch of different ways to do this without success. Hopefully, I can get some insights

```js
$('.pm-providerNum').each(function (index) {
        $(this).html('Providor ' + (index + 1));
    });

  $("div.pm-providor-first-wrap").each(function (index) {

        $(this).find('input').each(function () {
            $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name')+ '-' + index);

        })
    });

$(document).on("click", ".pm-add-loc-Class", function () {
    var $sect = $(this).closest(".pm-loc-section");
    $sect.find(".pm-loc-inputWrapper").eq(0).clone().show().insertBefore($sect.find(".pm-loc-controls")).find('input').val('');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="col-sm-12 pm-submitProvidor">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <div class="">
     <h4><span class="pm-providerNum"></span></h4>
     <div class="pm-providor-first-wrap">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-first_name" placeholder="First Name" required="" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-1">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-middle_name" placeholder="M" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required="" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-dob" placeholder="Date of birth" required="" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-personal_num" placeholder="Personal Phone #" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-personal_email" placeholder="Personal Email" required="" type="text">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-degree" placeholder="Degree" required="" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-3">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-d_date" placeholder="Date" required="" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-3">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-dobe" placeholder="Data of board exam" required="" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-3">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-nri_num" placeholder="NRI #" required="" type="text">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-prim_spec" placeholder="Primary Speciality" required="" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-sec_spec" placeholder="Secondary Speciality" required="" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-practice_name" placeholder="Practice name" required="" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-practice_num" placeholder="Practice Phone #" required="" type="text">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row" style="padding-left:15px; padding-right:15px;">
      <div class="pm-loc-section">
       <div class="pm-loc-inputWrapper">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3">
          <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Practice Physical Address" required="" type="text">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
          <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="City" required="" type="text">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-1">
          <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="State" required="" type="text">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
          <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Zip" required="" type="text">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="pm-loc-controls text-right">
        <input class="pm-add-loc-Class" type="button" value="+ Add Another Location">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div class="">
     <h4><span class="pm-providerNum"></span></h4>
     <div class="pm-providor-first-wrap">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-first_name" placeholder="First Name" required="" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-1">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-middle_name" placeholder="M" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required="" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-dob" placeholder="Date of birth" required="" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-personal_num" placeholder="Personal Phone #" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-personal_email" placeholder="Personal Email" required="" type="text">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-degree" placeholder="Degree" required="" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-3">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-d_date" placeholder="Date" required="" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-3">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-dobe" placeholder="Data of board exam" required="" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-3">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-nri_num" placeholder="NRI #" required="" type="text">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-prim_spec" placeholder="Primary Speciality" required="" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-sec_spec" placeholder="Secondary Speciality" required="" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-practice_name" placeholder="Practice name" required="" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-practice_num" placeholder="Practice Phone #" required="" type="text">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row" style="padding-left:15px; padding-right:15px;">
      <div class="pm-loc-section">
       <div class="pm-loc-inputWrapper">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3">
          <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Practice Physical Address" required="" type="text">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
          <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="City" required="" type="text">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-1">
          <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="State" required="" type="text">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
          <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Zip" required="" type="text">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="pm-loc-controls text-right">
        <input class="pm-add-loc-Class" type="button" value="+ Add Another Location">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div class="">
     <h4><span class="pm-providerNum"></span></h4>
     <div class="pm-providor-first-wrap">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-first_name" placeholder="First Name" required="" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-1">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-middle_name" placeholder="M" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required="" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-dob" placeholder="Date of birth" required="" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-personal_num" placeholder="Personal Phone #" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-personal_email" placeholder="Personal Email" required="" type="text">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-3">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-degree" placeholder="Degree" required="" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-3">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-d_date" placeholder="Date" required="" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-3">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-dobe" placeholder="Data of board exam" required="" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-3">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-nri_num" placeholder="NRI #" required="" type="text">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-prim_spec" placeholder="Primary Speciality" required="" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-sec_spec" placeholder="Secondary Speciality" required="" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-practice_name" placeholder="Practice name" required="" type="text">
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-2">
        <input class="pm-psubmit" name="p-practice_num" placeholder="Practice Phone #" required="" type="text">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row" style="padding-left:15px; padding-right:15px;">
      <div class="pm-loc-section">
       <div class="pm-loc-inputWrapper">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3">
          <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Practice Physical Address" required="" type="text">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
          <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="City" required="" type="text">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-1">
          <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="State" required="" type="text">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
          <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Zip" required="" type="text">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="pm-loc-controls text-right">
        <input class="pm-add-loc-Class" type="button" value="+ Add Another Location">
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see in your code that you're ever setting the `name` attribute so I'm not clear as to what you're asking or what the problem is. Are you asking how to set the `name` attribute in the way you described? What have you attempted, if anything, so far?

Comment: @DrewG yes, I want to add dynamically not in HTML, because the list can be a lot or less based on client. my attempts were messy and were breaking the clone. I wanted to give a clean snippet. sorry

Comment: I suggest you find a better way to handle datasets than giving every cell a unique id.  If you are processing this with php there is always a way to handle dynamically added data by only having assigned the `name=“myfield[]”` array-like syntax, possibly by storing the row id in a hidden form field, similarly tagged with `name=“id[]”` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way: For each "providor" group have all the input name attributes begin with something like `provider[index]` and then have each particular field's name be a second dimension input: `provider[1][firstname]`, `provider[1][lastname]`, etc.

Then, for your location fields, add an additional index to the end to indicate which location group it's part of:

- `provider[1][city][1]`
- `provider[1][state][1]`
- `provider[1][city][2]`
- `provider[1][state][2]`

etc.

You can also use the .data() function to store the providor index and location index in a manner you can later grab more easily.

Here is a working example:

```js
 $('.pm-providerInputGroup').each(function (index)
 {
 
  var inputGroupId = index + 1;
  var groupEl = $(this);
  
  groupEl.data('groupId', inputGroupId);
  
  groupEl.find('.pm-providerNum').html('Providor ' + inputGroupId);
  
  groupEl.find('.pm-psubmit').each(function()
  {
   var cleanName = $(this).attr('placeholder').toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/g, '');
   $(this).attr('name', 'providor[' + inputGroupId + '][' + cleanName + ']');
  });
  
  groupEl.find('.pm-loc-section .pm-loc-inputWrapper').each(function(index2)
  {
   var locGroupId = index2 + 1;
   
   $(this).data('locGroupId', locGroupId);
   
   $(this).find('.pm-psubmit').each(function()
   {
    var curName = $(this).attr('name');
    $(this).attr('name', curName + '[' + locGroupId + ']');
   });
  });
 
 });
 
 
 $(document).on("click", ".pm-add-loc-Class", function()
 {
     var $sect = $(this).closest(".pm-loc-section");
 
     var lastLocGroup = $sect.find(".pm-loc-inputWrapper").eq(-1);
 
  var lastLocGroupId = lastLocGroup.data('locGroupId');
 
     var newLocGroup = lastLocGroup.clone();
 
  var newLocGroupId = lastLocGroupId+1;
 
     newLocGroup.show().insertBefore($sect.find(".pm-loc-controls")).find('input').val('');
     
     newLocGroup.data('locGroupId', newLocGroupId);
 
     newLocGroup.find('.pm-psubmit').each(function(index2)
  {
   var curName = $(this).attr('name');
   var newName = curName.replace(/(\w+\[[^\]]+\]\[[^\]]+\])(\[[^\]]+\])/, '$1[' + newLocGroupId + ']' );
   $(this).attr('name', newName);
  });
 });
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="col-sm-12 pm-submitProvidor">
   <ul>
    <li>
     <div class="pm-providerInputGroup">
 
      <h4><span class="pm-providerNum"></span></h4>
 
      <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="First Name" required="" type="text">
      <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="M" type="text">
      <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Last Name" required="" type="text">
      <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Date of birth" required="" type="text">
      <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Personal Phone #" type="text">
      <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Personal Email" required="" type="text">
      <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Degree" required="" type="text">
      <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Date" required="" type="text">
      <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Data of board exam" required="" type="text">
      <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="NRI #" required="" type="text">
      <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Primary Speciality" required="" type="text">
      <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Secondary Speciality" required="" type="text">
      <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Practice name" required="" type="text">
      <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Practice Phone #" required="" type="text">
 
      <div class="row" style="padding-left:15px; padding-right:15px;">
       <div class="pm-loc-section">
        <div class="pm-loc-inputWrapper">
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
           <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Practice Physical Address" required="" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
           <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="City" required="" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1">
           <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="State" required="" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
           <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Zip" required="" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4"></div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pm-loc-controls text-right">
         <input class="pm-add-loc-Class" type="button" value="+ Add Another Location">
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </li>
    <li>
     <div class="pm-providerInputGroup">
 
      <h4><span class="pm-providerNum"></span></h4>
 
      <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="First Name" required="" type="text">
      <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="M" type="text">
      <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Last Name" required="" type="text">
      <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Date of birth" required="" type="text">
      <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Personal Phone #" type="text">
      <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Personal Email" required="" type="text">
      <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Degree" required="" type="text">
      <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Date" required="" type="text">
      <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Data of board exam" required="" type="text">
      <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="NRI #" required="" type="text">
      <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Primary Speciality" required="" type="text">
      <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Secondary Speciality" required="" type="text">
      <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Practice name" required="" type="text">
      <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Practice Phone #" required="" type="text">
 
      <div class="row" style="padding-left:15px; padding-right:15px;">
       <div class="pm-loc-section">
        <div class="pm-loc-inputWrapper">
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
           <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Practice Physical Address" required="" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
           <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="City" required="" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-1">
           <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="State" required="" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
           <input class="pm-psubmit" placeholder="Zip" required="" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4"></div>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pm-loc-controls text-right">
         <input class="pm-add-loc-Class" type="button" value="+ Add Another Location">
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
 
     </div>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: wow this works like a charm. The only problem is when i add the jquery code to my existing js file, the clone naming is not working. I am getting a "Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined" error. here's my fiddle . in the fiddle add button is not creating new inputs, but it is in my local just not naming currectly
  https://jsfiddle.net/jaisil007/dscynarr/4/

Comment: That fiddle is giving me an unrelated error on load: "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).accordion is not a function"

Comment: hmm, may have to post it as another question, ur code is working great by itself. In my local, i have jquery ui and accordion is working, it says "Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined". in jfiddle if I remove accordion it works. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: No problem :) Good luck